# Convert string to integer with CINT

Tags: vb.net

```
Const gconintRows1st As Integer = 15
 Const gconintRows4th As Integer = 20
```

I am trying to convert String to Integer

by using:

```
intNumber = CInt(strNumberSelected(intFirst5Balls))
```

Professor's

```
intTemperature = CInt(strTemperatures(intMonth))
```

But some how this does not work.

The professor's version worked fine but I cannot figure out why the intNumber does not.

Yes, this is my first time doing vb

Comment: what is the return value of `strNumberDrawn`?

Comment: I am supposed to be taking ball number and converting it from the split array

Comment: what I did was I took a guess at how I could have converted it @bansi

Comment: you are missing a `)` that may be a typo. But is `strNumberSelected(intFirst5Balls)` returning something which can be converted to integer? can you post relevant parts of function `strNumberSelected`?

Comment: what error message does it say? there should be something that tells why it does not work.

Comment: Its supposed to read from lines 3 to 55 on my list

Comment: all you are answering is useless, please just show your strNumberSelected function

Comment: the error reads char cannot be converted into an integer @Saechel

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like strNumberSelected is a string array, correct?  And you're asking for the string in the array at position intFirst5Balls?

Take this for an example:

```
Dim strArray As String() = Split("Hi|there|everybody", "|")
```

The Split() function will split our long string at each occurrence of a pipe ("|").

The resulting string array will have the following 3 elements:

```
"Hi"
"there"
"everybody"
```

And you'd reference these elements by their indexes:

```
 strArray(0) = "Hi"
 strArray(1) = "there"
 strArray(2) = "everybody"
```

If you're getting the error **'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Integer'** then your array is more likely an array of type **Char**, and the CInt() function cannot convert it to an integer.

You can use

```
 Integer.TryParse()
```

to try to get a valid Integer from your array, but it sounds a bit like you're unsure what sort of data actually lives in the array.